# Get author_id in wordpress

Tags: loop, author

I'm having problems to get author_id in this code. Don't show nothing. Some can help me?

```
<?php global $query_string;

query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=rand' ); ?>

<?php while(have_posts()): the_post();
$author_id = the_author_meta('ID');
echo 'Autor:'.$author_id;
$ofertas = array();

// Second Loop
$i = 0;
$args = array(
    'author' => $author_id,
    'post_type' => 'ofertas'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); // check if it has offers, if it has, loop over the offers
        $ofertas[$i]['title'] = get_the_title(); // or anything you need
        $i++;
    endwhile; // close the loop
else: // if it has no post
    continue; // we don't display the post
endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Author of what? Where are you running this?

Comment: Author of post, @Rarst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value in the `get_query_var()` function. An example, that works:--

```
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
echo $author->ID;
```

If you like only the author of post, inside the loop, then use the template tag [`get_the_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author).

Comment: thanks @bueltge but i have the code, the problem is get $ofertas in al posts... I improve my code for you can see it

Comment: I have enhanced for your hint.

Answer (score 3):

[`the_author_meta()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_author_meta/) echoes result immediately, use [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_author_meta/) to retrieve information you need to assign to a variable.